# Average without grouping or subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, average

I realize this is an odd question, but I'd like to know if this is possible.

Let's say I have a DB with ages and IDs.  I need to compare each ID's age to the average age, but I can't figure out how to do that without grouping or subqueries.

```
SELECT
ID,
AGE - AVG(AGE)
FROM
TABLE
```

I'm trying to get something like the above, but obviously that doesn't work because ID isn't grouped, but I group, then it calculates the average for each group, and not the table as a whole.  How can I get a global average without a subquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 SELECT ID,
        AGE -
        AVG(AGE) OVER (partition by ID) as age_2
 FROM Table
```

I just read is global `avg`

```
 SELECT ID,
        AGE -
        AVG(AGE) OVER () as age_2
 FROM Table
```

Comment: Not exactly, but it helped me get what I wanted!  Thank you so much.  I didn't realize you could have the OVER clause without the GROUP BY.  I needed `AGE - AVG(AGE) OVER(ORDER BY ID)`

Comment: Yes, I put both option, didnt I?

Comment: remember accept this answer if help you with your problem

Comment: @user3908206 I update my answer, even when documentation say `order by` is require that is a mistake for `AVG()`. So just remove that part

Answer (score 1):

The window logic for average age is:

```
SELECT ID, AGE - ( AVG(AGE) OVER () )
FROM TABLE;
```

You do not want `ORDER BY` in the partitioning clause.

Comment: In https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177677.aspx say `order_by_clause determines the logical order in which the operation is performed. order_by_clause is **required**.` Im incorrect on putting a default `order by` ?

Comment: The documentation is incorrect in this case. I just tried an empty over clause on a table that I have here and it produced the correct data. But ask yourself: why would an order by clause be required? You're not asking for a running average (which you'd do with a windowing clause anyways). `AVG()` is an order-independent aggregate.

Comment: @BenThul They probably copy/paste the documentation from the `row_number()` function.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get a global average without a subquery?

Use a variable.

```
DECLARE @AvgAge decimal(4,3)
SELECT @AvgAge = AVG(AGE) FROM TABLE
SELECT ID, AGE - @AvgAge [AgeDiff] FROM TABLE
```